# Lose files/data when removing bootcamp partition?

Tags: boot-camp, boot-partition

By removing the bootcamp partition on my iMac, will I lose all my files on the bootcamp side?  Or does it automatically save all that data on my iMac drive?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a partition will cause all files and folders in that partition to be lost.